# Safe [Y/N]; [1/2/3/etc.] function

Tags: c++, input, types, while-loop, comparison

I tried to make a an introduction to a "game", and in its functions I made some Yes/No, 1/2/3, situations. 
Im new to this however it wasn't that difficult, worked perfectly. The problem appeared when handling with invalid inputs. So this is what the code looks like by now:

```
#include "Introduction.h"
#include "GameConstants.h"
#include "PlayerCharacter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

Introduction::Introduction()
{

}

/////////Function N.1///////////
void Introduction::presentation()
{
    char confirm;
    string enteredName;

    cout << constants.line() << "Welcome traveler! What is the name?" << endl;
    getline(cin,enteredName);// Gets the WHOLE LINE as the name.

    while (confirm != 'Y') //If the player doesn't confirm the name with 'Y' in will run again until it does.
    {
        cout << constants.xline() << "Your name is " << enteredName << " right? (Y/N)" << endl;
        cin >> confirm; //The player's answer
        cin.sync(); //Only takes the first character
        confirm = toupper(confirm); //Turns player message into CAPS for easier detection in the "if" statements

        if (confirm == 'N'){ //If not the correct name, gives another chance
            cout << constants.xline() << "Please, tell me your name again..." << endl;
            cin >> enteredName;
            cin.sync();}

        if ((confirm != 'Y')&&(confirm != 'N')){ //If an invalid input is entered, gives another chance. And insults you.
            cout << constants.xline() << "Fool Go ahead, just enter your name again." << endl;
            cin >> enteredName;
            cin.sync();}
        }

    if (confirm == 'Y'){ //When the answer is yes ('Y') /* Uneeded line */
        PC.setName(enteredName); //Saves the name
        cout << constants.xline() << "Excellent! I have a few more questions for you " << PC.name() << "..." << endl;
    }
}


//////////Function N.2///////////
void Introduction::difSelection(){
    int selectedDif = 0; //Variable to store selected difficulty whitin this function.

    Sleep(2500);

    cout << constants.xline() << "What kind of adventure do you want to take part in?" << endl;

    Sleep(2500); //Wait 2,5 s

    cout << "\n1= Easy\n2= Normal\n3= Hard" << endl;

    while(selectedDif != 1&&2&&3){ //Selected option must be 1/2/3 or will run again
        cin >> selectedDif; //Sets the user selected difficulty
        cin.sync(); //Gets only first character 
        if((selectedDif != 1||2||3)&&(!(selectedDif))){ //If the input isn't 1/2/3 AND is an invalid character, this will run. And it'll start again

            cout << constants.xline() << "Criminal scum. Go again." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
        }

        if(selectedDif != 1&&2&&3){ //If selected option isn't 1/2/3, this will run and will loop again. However I know this conflicts with the previous statement since this will run anyways.

        cout << constants.xline() << "Wrong input, please try again." << endl;
        } 
        else if(selectedDif == 1){
        constants.setDiff(1);
        constants.setStatPoints(15);
        } else if(selectedDif == 2){
        constants.setDiff(2);
        constants.setStatPoints(10);
        } else if (selectedDif == 3){
        constants.setDiff(3);
        constants.setStatPoints(5);}
    }

}
```

The first function works perfectly you can type "aaa" or "a a a" and will work. However I'd like to know if there's a simpler way to do it. (Understandable for a beginner, just started 3 days ago lol; if it includes some advanced or less known code prefer to stay like this by now).

Now, the second one, I really have no idea how to fix it. I need something that if the user's input was an invalid character type, throw certain message, and if it's an int type, but out of the range, another message. And of course, run again if it fails. Did a lot of search and couldn't find anything that meet this requirements.

Comment: Some constructive criticism

1. You're checking confirm before it was even initialized which is bad practice. Consider a do-while loop instead of a while loop to allow the name check to happen once before checking the value of confirm
2. your if-blocks are poorly indented. Also this is prime candidate for the "switch" control structure.
3. Is PC a global? where is it defined?
4. How exactly is the second function failing? what happens when it compiles/executes?
5. Also, you can't do if (selectedDiff != 1&&2&&3) in c++. You have to compare against each value separately.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the user input is an int, you could use the `good()` function.

```
int val;
cin >> val;

if( cin.good() ) {
    // user input was a valid int
} else {
    // otherwise
}
```

As for the range check, the syntax is a bit different.
This returns true if the number is not equal to 1 nor 2 nor 3:

```
selectedDif != 1 && selectedDif != 2 && selectedDif != 3
```

Another shorter way would be to use:

```
selectedDif < 1 || selectedDif > 3
```

Another thing, in c++, there are two keywords `break` and `continue` which will allow to reduce the code in the loops.